# How can I disable the Close button of a waitbar in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I want to create a waitbar that should be processed without any interruption. How can I achieve this?

I have tried setting

```
h=waitbar(0,'please wait','CreateCancelBtn','setappdata(gcbf,''Cancel'',0)');
```

This disables the Close button on the waitbar, but it also shows me a Cancel button too. I don't want that button.

Answer (score 2):

When you use the `CreateCancelBtn` option of `waitbar`, it creates a Cancel button, takes the string you supply, and then sets that string to be **both** the Callback of the Cancel button (i.e. the thing that happens when you press the button) **and** the CloseRequestFcn of the figure window (i.e. the thing that happens when you click the Close button on the window frame).

You can avoid this by just directly setting the CloseRequestFcn of the figure window yourself:

```
h = waitbar(0,'Please Wait...');
h.CloseRequestFcn = '';
```

The Close button is now disabled.

Bear in mind that the CloseRequestFcn is also what gets executed when you call `close(h)`, so you now won't be able to close it with `close(h)`. You can either call `delete(h)` instead, or you can make sure that before you call `close(h)` you reset the CloseRequestFcn back to the default, which is the buit-in function `closereq` (type `edit closereq` to see what this does, it basically just calls `delete` anyway).

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks it helps me, I have one question, how I can disable Minimize button?